# Strange character square + 0101 in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-unicode

I am collecting temperature from a digital sensor connected to an i2c port in a Raspberry running on Ubuntu Core and I am using the following code:

```
import pigpio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    print("no pi")
    exit()

bus = 1
address = 0x5a
read_bytes = 9

while True:
    handle = pi.i2c_open(bus,address)
    count, data = pi.i2c_read_device(handle, read_bytes)

    pi.i2c_close(handle)
    pi.stop()

    print(count)
    print(data)

    exit()
```

However, the code returns a weird character for temperature, as seen below:

[image]

How can I transform this character into a readable number ? Is this somewhat related to unicode ?

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80207/strange-return-from-pigpio-i2c-read-device

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the data you are trying to print contains non-printable ascii codes. You can convert them to hex values and then decode them according to your sensor's datasheet:

```
print [ hex(x) for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be even broader than that. Since you are reading raw bytes, being able to print your data depends entirely on how those bytes are encoded. My suggestion is to convert them to hexadecimal using `hex(x)`, and then print them. After all, we are dealing wiht a `bytearray` type! Post that image here and we might help you a bit more!

Check the output of:

```
print ([int(x) for x in data])
print ([hex(x) for x in data])
```